# How do I send a list of different objects back as a JSON object through a .NET web service?

Tags: c#, .net, json

Let's say I have the following models:

```
 AnimalModel   
    DogModel : AnimalModel
    CatModel : AnimalModel
    ElephantModel : AnimalModel
```

And I want to return List as a JSON object in my web service... how can I do this best?

Keep in mind that with the sorting above, ElephantModel inherits from AnimalModel but clearly includes different class members that AnimalModel wouldn't have. (ie. TrunkSize) and I think this is what's causing the error.

Right now I have:

```
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "?query={query}")]
List<AnimalModel> Animals (string query);

[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "?query={query}")]
ElephantModel Elephant (string query);
```

If I just make a function like List and try to send it back, it seems to throw a fit. If I seralize it into a JSON string first, it passes the string--but then I have to parse it on my end again.

However, if I do this for just an ElephantModel or just a CatModel, it works perfectly! No serialization necessary, no parsing on the other end... works like a champ.

It's when I try to send a list of models that the child models inherit from that it breaks. However, if I can serialize it into a proper JSON string, send it, and receive that string to parse, there has to be something better I can do!

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean it throws a fit? What sort of error do you see?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).  Serializing and Deserializing is a snap.

```
//your object
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

//serialize it 
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);

//will look like this :
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": new Date(1230422400000),
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}


//on the 'other end' you just deserialize it with one line of code!
Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
```